# Debugging "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings" in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My database.php file have this code

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '*****';
$db['default']['password'] = '*****';
$db['default']['database'] = '********';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I am getting this error:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Filename: core/Loader.php Line Number: 346

I have tried $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; to both mysql and mysqli. Also  $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; to both TRUE and FALSE

also I have created a testing file in which i gave same credentials, it works there but its not working for website. I have placed this file in the home directory and it works fine. which simply means that username, password and hostname are correct.

here is testing.php

```
<?php

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '*****';
$db['default']['password'] = '*****';
$db['default']['database'] = '*******';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

mysql_connect($db['default']['hostname'],$db['default']['username'],$db['default']['password']);
mysql_select_db($db['default']['database']);

$row1=mysql_query("select * from pages");
while($qry1=mysql_fetch_row($row1)){

         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($qry1);
}


?>
```

I have tried multiple options which are available, but none of them is working for me.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? How does it not work? What error are you getting? How about the code you're actually using to query the database in Codeigniter?

Comment: this is what i am getting 

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Filename: core/Loader.php Line Number: 346

Comment: its when i am trying to open the admin page for website.

Comment: Are the Codeigniter and your test script on the same server?

Comment: yes i created test script to just confirm the credentials, both the codeigniter and testing.php is on same server

Comment: And what is your Codeigniter version?

Comment: If your using Codeigniter 3 version does not have mysql use mysqli as shown here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html#explanation-of-values

Comment: I am using  2.1.4 version of codeigniter.

@wolfgang1983: I have tried mysqli and also mssql for $db['default']['dbdriver'], which were suggested on other posts.

Comment: I would recommend using latest codeigniter

Comment: Try switching `$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;` to `FALSE`

Comment: @budwiser: done, but its still not working and populating the same error.